# Es buena practica exponer una clase AuthenticationService en la vista

Tags: javascript, angular

tengo la siguiente clase

```
export class AuthenticationService {
 
..
..
     } }
```

y la siguiente funcion isPermit la cual me valida el rol

```
    isPermit (rolesNoPermit = ['VIEWER']) {    
    ..    
    .. 
    }
```

Ahora en la vista hago el llamado de la siguiente forma

```
<a ..>
         <i *ngIf="_authenticationService.isPermit()"></i>

                </a>
```

Entonces no se si es buena practica llamar _authenticationService.isPermit() en la vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, no es buena practica.

preferiblemente en el `.component.ts` crees una funcion que retorne el valor

```
get isPermit(){
  return _authenticationService.isPermit()
}
```

y en el `.component.html`

```
*ngIf="isPermit"
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no es una buena práctica?

Comment: @Lobos cada quien es libre de desarrollar como bien pueda. En angular, algunos servicios suelen tener datos sensibles, por eso se suele mantener los servicios como privados y que el ts, sea el que mantenga la comunicacion con el html. todo lo que tiene contacto con el html es public, y lo que es public puede ser accesible de cualquier lado que se consulte.

Comment: Si es por tema de seguridad entonces no tiene efecto, todo lo que está del lado del cliente puede ser accedido. Así que "ocultar" servicios en realidad no logra nada.